# What is a 'Yoke' in NEC / electrician parlance?

Tags: electrical, nec, terminology

NEC rules sometimes refer to "the yoke".

For example: 1999 NEC § 210-4(b):

> **Dwelling Units.** In dwelling units, a multiwire branch circuit
>   supplying more than one device or equipment on the same ***yoke*** shall be
>   provided with a means to disconnect simultaneously all ungrounded
>   conductors at the panelboard where the branch circuit originated.

What is meant by the term 'Yoke' as used in the NEC?

Comment: You should really be using the modern NEC when dealing with multi-wire branch circuits. Not least it requires common maintenance shutoff on every single MWBC regardless.  It also requires pigtailing of neutrals.

Answer (score 8):

The 'Yoke' is the structural frame of a receptacle or switch:
[image: yoke]

It is often metal, with holes for two captive mounting screws, and should almost certainly be grounded if a grounding conductor is present.

Examples:

- A light switch in a single-gang junction box has a single yoke.
- Receptacles (in North America) are often manufactured in a pair of two outlets on a single 'yoke', which can be installed into one single-gang junction box.

Comment: I believe the yoke pictured is for a (normal, dual) NEMA 5-15 receptacle.  It is "upside down" if you're used to receptacles being installed "like faces" in a home setting.  Right side up if you install receptacles the "safer modern commercial" way. The two sets of contacts are what mate with the grounding pin on a nema 5-15 plug.  That's some good connectivity between them and the ground screw isn't it?